# Why is rspec saying this method is not received with should_receive?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

My question is, why do I receive the following rspec error message? (code below)  I've stubbed the :update_payment method on the StripeSubscription model.  I've been at this for a couple of hours and am perplexed.

```
Failure/Error: @stripe_msub.should_receive(:update_payment).and_return(@stripe_msub)
       (#<StripeSubscription:0xb879154>).update_payment(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times



 ###Rspec test###
    describe "PUT 'update'" do
        context "signed-in teacher" do
           before(:each) do
            @teacher = Factory(:teacher)
            @teacher_upload = Factory(:teacher_upload,:teacher_id=>@teacher.id)
            @stripe_mplan = Factory(:stripe_plan)
            @new_stripe_card_token = 528
            @stripe_msub = Factory(:stripe_subscription,:teacher_id=>@teacher.id,:stripe_plan_id=>@stripe_mplan.id, :email=>@teacher.email,:account_status=>Acemt::Application::STRIPE_SUBSCRIPTION_ACCOUNT_STATUS[:active])
            @stripe_msub.stub!(:update_payment).and_return(@stripe_msub)
            StripeSubscription.stub!(:update_payment).and_return(@stripe_msub)
            StripeSubscription.stub!(:update_attributes).and_return(true)
            @stripe_customer = mock('Stripe::Customer')
            Stripe::Customer.stub!(:retrieve).with(@stripe_msub.stripe_customer_token).and_return(@stripe_customer)
            @stripe_customer.stub(:card=).and_return(true)
            @stripe_customer.stub(:save).and_return(true)
            test_sign_in(@teacher)
          end
          it "should update credit card information" do
            @stripe_msub.should_receive(:update_payment)
            Stripe::Customer.should_receive(:retrieve).with(@stripe_msub.stripe_customer_token).and_return(@stripe_customer)
            @stripe_customer.should_receive(:card=)
            @stripe_customer.should_receive(:save).and_return(@stripe_customer)

            put :update, :teacher_id=>@teacher.id, :stripe_subscription=>{:stripe_plan_id=>@stripe_msub.stripe_plan_id, :teacher_id=>@stripe_msub.teacher_id, :email=>@stripe_msub.email, :stripe_customer_token=>@stripe_msub.stripe_customer_token,:stripe_card_token=>@new_stripe_card_token,:account_status=>@stripe_msub.account_status}
            @teacher.stripe_subscription.should == @stripe_msub
            response.should redirect_to teacher_path(@teacher)

          end
        end #signed in teacher
      end #PUT update

###controller###
class StripeSubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_teacher
  before_filter :correct_teacher
  :
   def update
    #@stripe_subscription = StripeSubscription.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @stripe_subscription = @teacher.stripe_subscription
    if @stripe_subscription.update_payment(params[:stripe_subscription])
      #handle successful update
      flash[:success] = "Credit card updated"
      sign_in @teacher
      redirect_to @teacher
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  :
end

###model###
class StripeSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :email, :plan_id, :stripe_customer_token, :teacher_id, :account_status
  validates_presence_of :stripe_plan_id
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :teacher_id

  belongs_to :stripe_plan, :class_name=>"StripePlan"
  belongs_to :teacher
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: stripe_plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end

    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
      errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."

  end
  def update_payment(stripe_params)
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_customer_token)
      customer.card = stripe_params[:stripe_card_token]
      status = customer.save #update card info on Stripe
      update_attributes(stripe_params) #save StripeSubscription object
    end

    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      logger.error "Stripe error while updating your credit card: #{e.message}"
      errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the expectation on an object in your spec (`@stripe_msub`). In the controller however, you probably load a *teacher* from the database and get its subscription (`@stripe_subscription`).

Due to the roundtrip through the database, this object is not the same one as the one you set your expectation on, therefore the one you set your expection on (`@stripe_msub` in the spec) never receives the method call and therefore rspec complains.

To fix this, you would have to stub away all database calls and make sure, that your object from the spec appears in the controller. I don't know where exactly `@teacher` is set in the controller (I guess in one of the filters) so I can't give you the exact solution, but it will be something like this:

```
# I assume this is the implentation of your filter in the controller
def signed_in_teacher
  @teacher = Teacher.find_by_id(params[:teacher_id])
end

# Then you would have to add the following mocks/stubs to your spec
Teacher.should_receive(:find_by_id).once.with(@teacher.id).and_return(@teacher)
```

Comment: severin, I forgot to stub the Teacher.find_by_id() in a before_filter call. I upvoted and marked this as answer, thank you.